# Representation of 3D object in 1D?

Tags: geometry

I've seen pictures of a tesseract on Google, in what could be considered the representation of a 4D object in 2D. This being possible, is it possible to represent a 3D object (say a cube) in 1D? What would that look like? I can see how a square  be represented by a line in 1D. But is that of a 3D object possible in 1D?

Comment: It would look like an set of eight points. (In the same we we don't "fill in" the 3D faces and 2D faces of the hypercube, for visibility reasons, we wouldn't fill in the 2D and 1D faces of the cube.)

Comment: Any such representation would be a line segment. Usually the projection (or a cross-section) is used when producing such a representation. Those are continuous functions, and as such map a compact connected set (add convexity to this list if you use cross sections) to a compact connected set. On the line all the compact connected sets are line segments. A rather dull representation if you ask me.

Comment: Ok, I do concede Thomas Andrews' point :-)

Comment: BTW [Neil Sloane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_Sloane) has, among other things worked on the problem of trying to find a representative set of 2D-subspaces in 4D such that the cross sections would give "a useful description of the 4D object". I once had the pleasure of attending a talk where he described the relevant metric on the Grassmannian and his sets of optimal points (depending on the number of cross sections you can afford to buy). I'm afraid I wasn't particularly enlightened about the 4D-shape his slides were trying to describe. I do concede that this more likely a limitation

Comment: (cont'd) of my 4D-imagination. Anyway, IIRC his coworkers later got a head start into network coding, when they had seen metrics on Grassmannians, some design ideas, and such.